# Export results on Excel in Alfresco Explorer

Tags: java, multithreading, excel, jsf, alfresco

I'have a class that exports some data of DB in a .xls archive. When I click the button Export it start to do it but this method takes a long time and I need the user to continue using the application while.

My first idea was creating a thread but I can't pass the FacesContext through the main thread to the other, so I have another solution?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the source code for how the ACP export works (Admin Console, Export) because it will optionally run in the background.

Comment: I'm looking it and I found       `this.getActionService().executeAction(action, startNode);` but I don't know how to tell it to use the method I need to run.